# How to select build variant (Android) in GitHub Actions?

Tags: android, gradle, github-actions

In my GitHub Actions .yml I want to build separate build variants and add `signingConfig` later on.

[image]

In my `buildTypes` there are 3 build variants
When I run    `run: ./gradlew build` or  `run: ./gradlew test` it will always run all of these build variants.

Comment: Please post your code in code regions as text and not as images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the tests for a specific variant with
`./gradlew test<VariantName>UnitTest`.

Example: `./gradlew testDebugUnitTest` (replacing `<VariantName>` with the variant name `Debug`)

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line

---

For the `build` task there are no sub-tasks for all the variants.